# Basic chat bot not getting trained on domail.yml file

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, rasa, rasa-nlu

I am beginner in rasa. I am trying to create a chat bot. I have made basic changes in the template provided by the rasa chatbot. The issue is bot is not responding as per changes made in domain.yml file

i am expecting that my bot response as per story, intent and response mentioned. But it is not getting trained on the information provided.

domain.yml

```yaml
version: "3.1"

intents:
  - greet
  - goodbye
  - affirm
  - deny
  - mood_great
  - mood_unhappy
  - bot_challenge
  - beam_design

responses:
  utter_greet:
  - text: "Hey! I am  bot, How may i help you?"

  utter_cheer_up:
  - text: "Here is something to cheer you up:"
    image: "https://i.imgur.com/nGF1K8f.jpg"

  utter_did_that_help:
  - text: "Did that help you?"

  utter_happy:
  - text: "Great, carry on!"

  utter_goodbye:
  - text: "Bye"

  utter_iamabot:
  - text: "I am a bot, powered by Rasa."



  utter_beam_design_steps:
  - text: "Select Material"

session_config:
  session_expiration_time: 60
  carry_over_slots_to_new_session: true
```

stories.yml

```yaml
version: "3.1"

stories:

- story: happy path
  steps:
  - intent: greet
  - action: utter_greet
  - intent: mood_great
  - action: utter_happy

- story: sad path 1
  steps:
  - intent: greet
  - action: utter_greet
  - intent: mood_unhappy
  - action: utter_cheer_up
  - action: utter_did_that_help
  - intent: affirm
  - action: utter_happy

- story: sad path 2
  steps:
  - intent: greet
  - action: utter_greet
  - intent: mood_unhappy
  - action: utter_cheer_up
  - action: utter_did_that_help
  - intent: deny
  - action: utter_goodbye



- story: beam design
  steps:
  - intent: greet
  - action: utter_greet
  - intent: beam_design
  - action: utter_beam_design_steps
```

nlu.yml

```yaml
version: "3.1"

nlu:
- intent: greet
  examples: |
    - hey
    - hello
    - hi
    - hello there
    - good morning
    - good evening
    - moin
    - hey there
    - let's go
    - hey dude
    - goodmorning
    - goodevening
    - good afternoon

- intent: goodbye
  examples: |
    - cu
    - good by
    - cee you later
    - good night
    - bye
    - goodbye
    - have a nice day
    - see you around
    - bye bye
    - see you later

- intent: affirm
  examples: |
    - yes
    - y
    - indeed
    - of course
    - that sounds good
    - correct

- intent: deny
  examples: |
    - no
    - n
    - never
    - I don't think so
    - don't like that
    - no way
    - not really

- intent: mood_great
  examples: |
    - perfect
    - great
    - amazing
    - feeling like a king
    - wonderful
    - I am feeling very good
    - I am great
    - I am amazing
    - I am going to save the world
    - super stoked
    - extremely good
    - so so perfect
    - so good
    - so perfect

- intent: mood_unhappy
  examples: |
    - my day was horrible
    - I am sad
    - I don't feel very well
    - I am disappointed
    - super sad
    - I'm so sad
    - sad
    - very sad
    - unhappy
    - not good
    - not very good
    - extremly sad
    - so saad
    - so sad

- intent: bot_challenge
  examples: |
    - are you a bot?
    - are you a human?
    - am I talking to a bot?
    - am I talking to a human?




- intent: beam_design
  examples: |
    - how can I design rcc beam?
    - Steps to design a beam?
```

Answer (score 0):

model training is working fine at my end with your changes.

[image]

if you are using command `python -m rasa train` then make sure that you have delete all older models inside the models folder first then execute the train command. Platform have probably picked older  model when you start the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Model training works well on my end.

**Output**

```
Your input ->  how can i design rcc beam                                                    
Select Material
Your input ->  how can i create rcc beam                                                    
Select Material
```

---

```
Rasa Version      :         3.5.8
Minimum Compatible Version: 3.5.0 
Rasa SDK Version  :         3.5.1 
Python Version    :         3.9.16
Operating System  :         Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
```